# How to redirect back to previous page after invalid input

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I currently have the code below in a controller helper module. It allows me to redirect back to the previous page by grabbing the the conn's referrer. The problem with this is if there is a invalid input on a form for example, the conn's referrer is reset to the current page.

```
  def redirect_back(conn, alternative \\ "/") do
    path = conn
    |> get_req_header("referer")
    |> referrer
    path || alternative
  end

 defp referrer([]), do: nil
 defp referrer([h|_]), do: h
```

How can I hold the referrer to the correct previous page so I can use it to redirect even if something like an invalid input occurs?

Comment: so to clarify, you want to make it so that even if someone fails a form validation, it redirects back to the previous page (e.g. not the form page?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a [discussion in phoenix issues](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/1402#issuecomment-171088163) on the topic, that resulted in the [fancy small library](https://github.com/tuvistavie/plug-navigation-history) that you might want to include into your project and use like this:

```
def redirect_back(conn, alternative \\ "/") do
  conn |> NavigationHistory.last_path(default: alternative)
end
```

or in any other way, described in it’s README/help.